# SQLiteConnection, C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I installed the reference for "SQLite for Universal App Platform" in my Visual Studio 2015 project, later I installed the NuGet package "sqlite.net-pcl-silverlight"

I am trying the following lines:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Storage.sqlite"); 
SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```

It doesn't work but I found that this line is valid:

```
SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, dbPath);
```

My problem is that I don't know which should be the value of sqlitePlatform... Please help.

Comment: `var connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path)` should do the trick...

Comment: See here for more information: http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/11/25/sqlite-and-uwp

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly; SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I posted as an answer so that your question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

For UWP the same `sqlitePlatform` as WinRT should work. Go ahead and try this:

`var connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);`

That should work for you.